# How to free up the space taken by bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind

I am trying to create a wallet on my computer with `bitcoind` following [this guide](https://scottlinux.com/2013/09/09/how-to-setup-bitcoin-wallet-headless-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/#comment-1724). I installed it, ran it, and monitored the process with `bitcoin-cli`. It went on for about 15 hours, at which it failed with an error message: "Error: Error: Disk space is low!". `bitcoind` had taken up the whole 160 Gb available in my home disk.

How can I safely free up the space taken by `bitcoind`? Should it be uninstalled? Or delete files (which?) will suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quide you followed is 3 years old. Since then, there was an option added called `prune` - add it to a line in your *bitcoind.conf*, like so:

> prune=50000

And restart `bitcoind`. This would effectively limit your blockchain size to only 50Gb of recent blocks.

In case you need to have a full blockchain available for research & analysis, there is no other way but to buy a bigger HD.

In case you don't need the local blockchain at all, then there is very little reason not to use a lightweight client like `Electrum` which does not store anything on your HD but instead relies on proprietary servers.

Comment: I am now happily using Electrum.